Car Will not go into Gear. Stranded
Problem started two days ago. The car would struggle to get into first gear, from neutral at standstill, but with some resistance (NOT grinding) it would go (and same thing with second gear, with a bit less resistance.) Third and Fourth were fine, and Fifth gear was also a struggle.
Next day everything worked normally, the entire day.
This morning, reverse became impossible (gears would grind) and first gear will NOT go at all, not even with a little bit of resistance. However when I DO try to shift into first, the car "grabs" like it wants to pull forward, only it can't fully get into gear.
This model's brake fluid reservoir apparently doubles as the clutch fluid reservoir. The fluid is JUST above the "low" point, but I have no brake fluid nearby (thought I'd top it off in case that might have something to do with it.)
What is the likely culprit- possible failed clutch/ slave/ master cylinder?
What might account for the intermittent periods of normal functioning, followed by worsening of the problem?
Chat GPT says there could even be an electrical issue, but no relevant codes came up with my OBD scanner.
Car is not driveable in this condition. What else could it be, or what should I try?
Vehicle is Scion tC 2005, 146,000, mostly highway miles. Front wheel drive. Normal driving only, no clutch or transmission abuse.
Clutch pedal feels normal, no sponginess.
No visible leaks at clutch master cylinder.

Does it feel to move between the gear fine with the engine off?  I had a clutch get stuck once.  I had to turn the car off, put it in reverse, back up, shut the car off, put it in first, and start the car to drive in order to get it home.  Seems like an issue with the clutch releasing.  Likely master cylinder, slave cylinder, or throwout bearing.  If you can see the slave cylinder, you can watch while someone presses the clutch pedal to see how much it moves (or doesn't move).

Yes , it shifts fine when the engine is not running. Everything else you described is exactly my situation: starting it in reverse or first in order to drive temporarily.  I did watch the slave cylinder and it does seem to move the clutch fork normally. Do you think I can rule out the slave cylinder then, and the master cylinder? (I was gonna change them this weekend, but after watching the slave cylinder and clutch fork move, not so sure.) You could also be right about the throw out bearing, but I hope that's not it. What was ultimately the issue in your case?

In my case, the springs between the center section and outer section of the clutch disk had broken / popped out and wedged themself between the flywheel and clutch disk.

The slave cylinder moving is a descent sign, but I wonder if it is moving the entire range.    If there is an air bubble in the line, it may not move all the way.  Not sure if there a good, safe way to test this.  Might be able to look in a factory service manual.  Not sure how much you can see inside the bell housing to inspect the throwout bearing and pressure plate condition.

Thought this was interesting.  https://www.yoursciontc.com/threads/how-many-of-you-replaced-clutch-on-05-scion-tc.46921/  Someone mentioned on a 2005 Tc "On the stock clutch it had rubber dampers and with time and heat it just crumbled causing jamming and a lost of shifting in gear."  That's what happened on my clutch, except that mine had metal springs instead of rubber bushings.

Your other post mentioned driving on empty roads, mostly highway and minimum stops to your mechanic. Instead of 1st gear, start out in 2nd or 3rd. It's not great for the clutch, but if your choice is doing that once or twice or having a long-distance tow, just slip the clutch to get going and get it to your mechanic.
